# Order By in @Query select not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have this Query in my JPA repository - and it works EXCEPT the " order by " part. Am i doing this wrong ? is it different in hql ?

```
@Query(value = "select wm.WagerIdentification, wm.BoardNumber, wm.MarkSequenceNumber, wm.MarkNumber," +
        " pt.CouponTypeIdentification, pt.WagerBoardQuickPickMarksBoard " +
        "from WagerBoard wb " +
        "inner join wb.listOfWagerMarks wm  " +
        "inner join wb.poolgameTransaction pt  " +
        "where wb.WagerIdentification = wm.WagerIdentification and wb.BoardNumber = wm.BoardNumber and wb.GameIdentification = wm.GameIdentification and wm.meta_IsCurrent = 1 " +
        "and wb.TransactionIdentification = pt.TransactionIdentification and pt.meta_IsCurrent = 1 " +
        "and wb.meta_IsCurrent = 1 order by wm.WagerIdentification asc, wm.BoardNumber asc, wm.MarkNumber asc")
```

Comment: What code is annotated by `@Query`? (are you using a `List`?)

Comment: @RC. List<Object[]> findAllTest();

Comment: Instead of ordering result within the `@Query`, you can add a method parameter of type Sort, like in Spring Data JPA reference - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting

Comment: @RC. thanks, figured it out through your link.

Comment: Wasn't me, @bart.s you should transform your comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ordering result within the @Query, you can add a method parameter of type Sort, like in [Spring Data JPA reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting)